# How to make certain field not visible in an api output using python and django?

Tags: python, django

i have parent (AccessInternalSerializer) and child serializer (AccessSerializer) classes like below,

```
class AccessInternalSerializer(AccessBaseSerializer):
    private_key = serializers.FileField(
        allow_null= True,
        required=False)
    ca_cert=serializers.FileField(
        allow=True,
        required=False)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = super().to_representation(obj)
        data['private_key'] = obj.private_key
        data['ca_cert'] = obj.ca_cert
        return data
   
    class Meta(AccessBaseSerializer.Meta):
        model=Access
        extra_kwargs = {
           'auth_failure': {
               read-only: True
            }
        }
      
class AccessSerializer(AccessInternalSerializer): 
    private_key = serializers.FileField(
        write_only=True,
        allow_null=True,
        required=False)
    ca_cert=serializers.FileField(
        write_only=True,
        allow_null=True,
        required=False)
    class Meta(AccessInternalSerializer.Meta):
        extra_kwargs={
            **AccessInternalsSerializer.Meta.extra_kwargs,
            'private_key': {
                'write_only':True, 
            }
            'ca_cert': {
                'write_only': True,
            }
        }
```

Now with above code for some reason private_key and ca_cert are shown in the output of api using AccessSerializer.

with AccessInternalSerializer to_representation i make the private_key and ca_cert fields visible in api output that uses AccessInternalSerializer.

however it behaves the same using AccessSerializer.

i expect the api output to not return private_key and ca_cert fields using AccessSerializer.

I am not sure where i am going wrong. i am new to python and django programming. i am stuck with this from long time.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: If possible the share the full serializer file

Comment: thanks this is the serializer file. but what part of code is still needed. still i am new to django just trying to understand

Comment: If possible then add models please

Comment: I think there is an issue in inheriting the serializers. You can follow the following link to know more about nested relationships using serializers here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships